# Ubuntu will not update, I get an error

Tags: update-manager

Here is the error I get when trying to update Ubuntu:

```
Could not initialize the package information
An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:
'E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_binary-amd64_Packages, E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this with this command:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start System Settings and click on the Software and Updates icon, wait for that to load then click on the Other Software tab

[image: Other Software tab]

Make sure that all the checkboxes are un-ticked and perform a manual update running Software Updater.

[image]